# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (7\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (7\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx\ ?$$

This is the problem I have to solve. I have studied math up to 12 grade. Kindly help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

May be, you could start changing variable (just to get a simple sine in the top); say $x=\frac{y^2}{49}$, $dx=\frac{2y}{49}\,dy$. So $$\int \frac{\sin (7\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\frac 27\int \sin(y)\,dy=\frac 27 \cos(y)$$

Comment: That's really helpful for me!

Comment: @Bhaskara-III. Glad to help ! Now, what about the integral ?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}
\end{equation*}
so this suggests to do the change of variable $u=\sqrt{x},$ then $du=\frac{1%
}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$ and $dx=2\sqrt{x}du=2udu,$ so
\begin{equation*}
\int \frac{\sin (7\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int \frac{\sin (7u)}{u}%
(2udu)=2\int \sin (7u)du
\end{equation*}
I am sure you can take it from here...